# Image is not coming in Jquery POP Up

Tags: jquery, liferay

```
String mailBody = "<div style='margin-left:10px;'>"
                       +"<div style='font-weight: bold; font-size: 19px; padding-top: 8px;'>Anindya</div>"
                       +"<div style='font-size: 17px;'>Senior Salesforce with Oracle Developer</div>"
                       +"<div style='margin-top:5px;padding-bottom: 4px; font-size: 12px;'><img src="+resourceRequest.getContextPath()+"/images/icon/Mobile-phone.png\" height='16' width='16'></img>9830093200</div>"
                       +"<div style='padding-bottom: 4px; font-size: 12px;'><img src='../images/icon/location-icon.png' height='16' width='16'></img>Kolkata</div>"
                       +"<div style='display:inline-block;padding-bottom: 4px; font-size: 12px;'><img src='../images/icon/email-icon.png' height='16' width='16' style='float:left;margin-right:2px;'></img><div style='float:left;'>anindyamallik@gmail.com</div></div>"
                       +"</div>";

I want to show this string in a pop up, but while showing to pop up the
```

[image]images are not available. How to resolve that?

Can anyone  help me please??

Comment: Can you check the html generated? is generated image URL valid?

Comment: using firebug i can see that it shows failed to load the image URL

Comment: what is the value of resourceRequest.getContextPath() you are getting?

Comment: There must be issue with resourceRequest.getContextPath(). Try using request.getContextPath(), where request is httpServletRequest object. It will give you valid context path of the application.

Comment: This is very easy to troubleshoot in browser dev tools network. Look at the failed url's that are sent to server and adjust accordingly.

Comment: @ParkashKumar but this is Liferay we have resourceRequest only

Comment: Whatsoever, you can still have request object on your JSP, as it is an implicit object. Are you displaying your popup through AJAX call to server?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get dynamic context path on JSP page of your portlet, you can use `request.getContextPath()` of `HttpServletRequest` object as following:

**JSP:**

```
String mobileIcon = request.getContextPath()  + "/images/icon/Mobile-phone.png";
String locationIcon = request.getContextPath()  + "/images/icon/location-icon.png";
String emailIcon = request.getContextPath() + "/images/icon/email-icon.png";
```

While if you want to get it in action file, e.g. in `serveResource` method, you can get context name from `PortletContext` object as following:

**Action:**

```
PortletContext portletContext = resourceRequest.getPortletSession().getPortletContext();
String mobileIcon = "/" + portletContext.getPortletContextName()  + "/images/icon/Mobile-phone.png";
String locationIcon = "/" + portletContext.getPortletContextName()  + "/images/icon/location-icon.png";
String emailIcon = "/" + portletContext.getPortletContextName()  + "/images/icon/email-icon.png";
```

Comment: @Tobias Liefke, have you tested it on Linux / Unix environment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746419/file-separator-vs-file-pathseparator#answer-27746502

Comment: File.separator is a static util method, it is returning \ or / as string based on OS.