# How would I format a file location?

Tags: java

I have the variable `directory` which will be a directory that the user inputs, 
such as 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe". The issue is that the program doesn't recognize the directory, and thus won't launch it via `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {directory});`

How would I make a method/algorithm that takes every `\` from `directory` and turns it into a `\\`?

```
if (directory.substring(j, j+1).equals("\\"))
{
    //directory.substring(j, j+1) == "\\\\";
}
```

Ex:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

should turn into

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe
```

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Why don't you use `File.Separator` instead of constant notation?? I think you should take a look to this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746419/file-separator-vs-file-pathseparator

Comment: I don't think you want to do this.  There should be exactly one backslash character between each path component.  `"\\"` is just a *compile-time representation* of a single backslash.  When you type commands (like `cd`) in a Command Window, you don't double the backslashes.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap I don't need to take a look at anything. Question was: how to replace single backslashes with double backslashes. I don't need to make any further assumptions about OP's operating environment or the non-functional requirements of their application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace so `directory.replace("\\","\\\\");`

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I forgot about that method, but it worked. :)

Comment: No problem man. Everyone forgets sometimes

Comment: That won't even compile.

Comment: Whoops forgot about escape characters ill edit my answer

Comment: better to Use `File.separator` Constant to replace.. Cozz if you use a linux or unix based system this will not work.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746419/file-separator-vs-file-pathseparator

Answer (score -1):

```
string str = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
sb.Replace('\\', '\\\');
```

This replace all ! marks to o i hope this will help u.

**Edit:**

```
string str = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
str.Replace('\\', '\\\');
```

Comment: Obviously will not compile. It's a Java question.

Comment: which language u use

Comment: Never mind what I use. The question is tagged java. You're posting half-correct C# code.

Comment: how is this half correct.